# Don't understand the arguments for model.getAttr()

Tags: python, gurobi

I am new to Python and Gurobi and I was reading through the manual for model.getAttr and I understand that the arguments returned are model.getAttr(attrname,objs=None).

What I don't understand is the sample code provided below in the manual:

print(model.getAttr("Pi", model.getConstrs()))

The attrname "Pi" is not anywhere in my code, how come it is still able to return a value?

Please help!

```
 try:

    # Create a new model
    m = Model("simplelp")

    # Create variables
    x1 = m.addVar(ub = 10, name="x1")
    x2 = m.addVar(name="x2")
    x3 = m.addVar(name="x3")

    # Set objective
    m.setObjective(x1 + 2 * x2 + 5 * x3, GRB.MAXIMIZE)

    # Add constraint: 
    m.addConstr(-x1 + x2 + 3*x3 <= -5, "c0")

    # Add constraint: 
    m.addConstr(x1 + 3*x2 - 7*x3 >= 10, "c1")

    m.optimize()

    # print optimal solutions
    for v in m.getVars():                     #m.getVars() retrieves all the variables in the model, contains v 
        print('%s %g' % (v.varName, v.x))     #v.varName returns name, v.x returns value

    # print optimal value
    print('Obj: %g' % m.objVal)

    # print dual values to all constraints
    print(m.getAttr("Pi", m.getConstrs()))

except GurobiError as e:
    print('Error code ' + str(e.errno) + ": " + str(e))

except AttributeError:
    print('Encountered an attribute error')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you're mistaking something. "Pi" is an **attribute** of a Linear constraint **object** you create with the `m.addConstr()` method.  See [here](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.1/refman/attributes.html) for a overview of all available attributes.

Let's consider:

```
from gurobipy import Model, GRB

# Create a new model
m = Model("simplelp")

# Create variables
x1 = m.addVar(ub = 10, name="x1")
x2 = m.addVar(name="x2")
x3 = m.addVar(name="x3")

# Set objective
m.setObjective(x1 + 2 * x2 + 5 * x3, GRB.MAXIMIZE)

# Add constraint: 
con0 = m.addConstr(-x1 + x2 + 3*x3 <= -5, "c0")

# Add constraint: 
con1 = m.addConstr(x1 + 3*x2 - 7*x3 >= 10, "c1")

m.optimize()
```

Then `m.getConstrs()` returns a list containing all constraint objects:

```
In [16]: print(m.getConstrs())                                                                                                                          
Out[16]: [<gurobi.Constr c0>, <gurobi.Constr c1>]
```

while `m.getAttr(attrname, objectslist)` returns for all objects in objectslist the value of the attribute attrname:

```
In [18]: print(m.getAttr("Pi", [con0, con1]))                                                                                                               
Out[18]: [2.0, 0.0]

In [19]: print(m.getAttr("Pi", m.getConstrs()))                                                                                                         
Out[19]: [2.0, 0.0]

In [20]: print([con0.Pi, con1.Pi])                                                                                                                          
Out[20]: [2.0, 0.0]
```